# How do i make the value of one variable the name of another in python

Tags: python, variables

So, I have a variable called 'namer'. I want the name of another variable to be the value of 'namer'.

For example, if the value of 'namer' is 'name1', I want to create a variable called 'name1'.

How do I do this?

Comment: why would you do this?

Comment: No, you don't. Use a dict.

Comment: It would be great if you could show a [mcve] of how you would use these variables in your code